# Redirection to another website in razor application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to add an link in my Asp.net mvc4 application to `google.com`. So i add this snippet to my view :

```
 <p class="art-page-footer">
        <span id="art-footnote-links"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a></span>
    </p>
```

when i click into this link i have as an url `http://localhost:61961/User/www.google.com` and i have an exception.

So why this redirection didn't work? How can i fix my code?

Comment: Have you tried with `href="http://www.google.com"` ?

Comment: Yes it works now!! what is the difference between it?

Comment: MVC routes to con controllers, see some tutorials on routing in ASP.MVC.

Comment: Your href points to a resource inside your web site. With the http prefix it's able to go out of starting domain.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria : can you put your comment as answer please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with full URL:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

The `href` attribute takes an  `URL` of the link.

3 Possibles values:

1. **An absolute URL** : points to another web site (like
   href="http://www.google.com")
2. **A relative URL** : points to a file within a web site (like
   href="contacts.html")
3. **An anchor URL** : points to an anchor within a page (like href="#top")